Can I open the Solid door solving the hard puzzle in Lair of the Clockwork God?
In Lair of the Clockwork God, after you completed the second emotion construct, it's finally time to open a "solid door" with this absurd puzzle:

Of course you don't really have to solve it, because

there are explosive barrels upstairs that can be rolled down with the giant shovel-like lollipop, which then can be ignited

But I'm wondering:
Was it possible to open this door in the "wrong way" solving this really long puzzle?
